# Python error “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named libs.gpu.GpuWrapper”

Tags: python-3.x

I'm using CUDA 10.1 to compile a Python program. The main program can be found here [text_renderer](https://github.com/Sanster/text_renderer).

The command line arguments that can be passed are found in the file [parse_args.py](https://github.com/Sanster/text_renderer/blob/master/parse_args.py). I set the gpu parameter to be True by default.

```
parser.add_argument('--gpu', action='store_true', default=True, help="use CUDA to generate image")
```

I got the following error in line number `80` of [renderer.py](https://github.com/Sanster/text_renderer/blob/master/textrenderer/renderer.py):

```
from libs.gpu.GpuWrapper import cudaWarpPerspectiveWrapper
```

I am using a conda environment where I tried reinstalling CUDA and cuDNN but no success. The list of packages installed in my environment can be found here: [conda list](https://github.com/harshil-darji/text_renderer/blob/master/conda_list).

Comment: I don't understand anything in this question. CUDA can't "compile a Python program.". You "following error" isn't an error, it is a line of Python code. And the github code you link to does not contain any CUDA code at all. I have removed the CUDA tag from this, it has nothing to do with CUDA

Comment: The python code tries to import a module named GpuWrapper from CUDA packages. So, I think something is wrong with the installed CUDA packages (maybe version or something missing). Hence, I attached a list of packages I used to run the program in my conda environment so that someone knowing could inform me which package is missing.

Comment: There is no such thing as "GpuWrapper from CUDA packages" and I repeat, there is absolutely no CUDA code in that Github repo, nor anything to do with CUDA either. It looks like there is a wrapper around a few GPU accelerated OpenCV functions when the GPU is used